# Which metric should I use to rank these distributions?

Tags: distributions, ranking, kurtosis

I have a number of 1D distributions, which, when plotted show a distinct ranking in terms of the "spikiness" of the data. I would like to apply a relatively fast metric that would allow me to rank these data sets.

From what I've read so far (I'm not a statistician), it sounds like kurtosis is what I'm looking for. Could someone take a look at the three plots below (shown in the order I'd like them ranked) and let me know if I'm heading in the right direction or if there is a more suitable (faster or more robust) metric?

[image: leastdetail]

[image: mediumdetail]

[image: mostdetail]

As noted in comments, the data actually represents greyscale intensity levels across a 1D vector on an image. So the peaks relate to image features. The three plots are from the same position of the same image, just with varying degress of focus blur - the final plot being the "in-focus" state.

Comment: These look like time series rather than distributions. If they are distributions, they're multimodal and kurtosis would be of little use. How does the information plotted here arise? What are we looking at?

Comment: @Glen_b Apologies if I've used the wrong terminology - the plots represent intensity levels along a 1D vector on a grayscale image. Each plot represents a different level of focus blur.

Comment: Ah, so not time but effectively spatial. It would be good to edit the information you gave there into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want rank this images you don't need kurtosis - as it is of little use here. I think you should try an heuristic.

For example, you can estimate integral of absolute values of gradient w.r.t. x-axis, to do this you can sum up absolute values of differences between neighbour points along x-axis: for the first image the integral of the absolute value of gradient is smaller, for the last image the integral of absolute of gradient is bigger.

Comment: Ok, thanks - that sounds like something I can try easily and at least it rules out kurtosis, so I'm grateful for that too.